# Remove space in end Popup in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, popup, combobox

Доброго времени суток.

Каким способом можно убрать пустое место в конце?

[image]

Comment: Показали бы разметку Popup вашего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```